# Scala: how to write a tail-recursive function more idiomatically

Tags: scala

I have the following:

```
case class Node(parent: Option[Node], etc:Any)

@tailrec
def getAncestor(numGens:Int, node:Node): Option[Node] =
  if(numGens <= 0) Some(node)
  else node.parent match {
    case Some(parent) => getAncestor(numGens-1, parent)
    case None         => None
  }
```

I don't like the `case None => None`. It gives me the impression that there should be a more elegant way. However, if I replace the `else` with:

```
else node.parent.flatMap(p => getAncestor(numGens-1, p))
```

then the function is no longer tail-recursive. Is there a more idiomatic way of writing this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way. Your approach is already concise enough. Here are two other options:

```
// 1. changing argument type
@tailrec
def getAncestor(numGens:Int, node: Option[Node]): Option[Node] =
  if(numGens <= 0) node else getAncestor(numGens -1, node.flatMap(_.parent))

// 2. removing if
@tailrec
def getAncestor(numGens:Int, node:Node): Option[Node] =
  node.parent match {
    case _ if numGens <= 0 => Some(node)
    case Some(parent) => getAncestor(numGens-1, parent)
    case _ => None
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@tailrec
def getAncestor(numGens:Int, node:Node): Option[Node] = {
  node.parent match {
    case Some(parent) if numGens > 0           => getAncestor(numGens - 1, parent)
    case Some(_) | None if numGens == 0        => Some(node)
    case _                                     => None
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this does not work when numGens = 0; it should return Some(node) in that case

Comment: I think the second case should be `_`

Comment: Yes. Maybe the last two cases could be simplified into one: `case _ => if(numGens==0) Some(node) else None`

Comment: Then, that wouldn't be the idiomatic way and readability is compromised.

Comment: Even more concise would be `case _ => Some(node).filter(_ => numGens == 0)`

Comment: Nope, you are trying to filter an `Option` with a condition that has nothing to do with contained `Some` value as you are ignoring it.

Comment: You can just write `_` instead of `Some(_) | None`. I also disagree that Eduardo's suggestion is unidiomatic or compromises readability significantly.

Answer (score 0):

This case class doesn't seem very useful.  Since each node has only one parent, what you have done is recreate `List[Any]` without any of the useful methods.

If you put your `etc` objects into a List, then `getAncestor(i, n)` simply becomes

```
ns drop i
```

The result will either be a shorter list with the desired node at the top or an empty list.  No memory will be wasted because Scala's immutable list is a [persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).  You can retrieve the contents of the new head node with

```
ns.drop(i).headOption
```

No stackoverflows, no ugliness caused by trying to make a recursive function tail recursive (*useful* explicitly recursive functions almost always end up ugly when made tail recursive).  Much more idiomatic Scala because it is using the right type for the job.

If you *are* trying to build some more complex kind of structure with your nodes, then you would do better to build a proper Algebraic Data Type using case classes extending a sealed trait (or sealed abstract base class).  Need more information about your intentions before expanding on that idea, though.

Comment: No. The data structure I have allows trees. It is not a list.

Comment: I suspected as much but it doesn't look like a good way to build a tree.  If you use a well designed ADT structure, as I mentioned, functions/methods which traverse it will become much cleaner.  Not least because they can pattern match on meaningful types.

Comment: As it is, what you have build *here* is `List[Any]`.  You may be using it as part of a tree structure, but what you have here is a list, which is not a good thing to build trees from.